# Why does a random number geometric node sometimes need an ID?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Why does a randomly generated number sometimes need a mandatory ID? I'm currently reluctantly putting a random value just so it works. It works on the right screenshot without an ID. I can see though there is a broken line for the case where it treats the ID optionally.

[image]

Comment: If you tried to connect *Random Angle* to your *"Plant.."* node, or *Random Value* to your *Angle to Radians* node, you would see your problem is not about the random nodes at all :)

Comment: sorry i was supposed to ask for the purpose XD but nevermind it's fine thank you for the quick response!

Comment: well it's fine i think i found it https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/nodes/function/nodes/node_fn_random_value.cc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it doesn't "need" it. you have to differentiate between different type of input/outputs. The round sockets are single values/vectors, the diamond shaped are functions/multiple/calculated values.
The random value node "normally" is a function which gives multiple different random values. But if you want to plug that into a round socket of another node it won't work because you have to plug in round in round and diamond in diamond. So you can change the random value from multiple values to only one value by plugging in a ID and you will see that the diamond output changes to a round output.

Comment: hey thank you for the quick response! hmmm maybe i should have rephrased the question. I was wondering what the purpose of the ID is for single values. Why would a function of values not require an ID and a single require an ID.. i'll probably have to check it's usage in the open source code on git hub XD

Comment: ah i think i found it. https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/nodes/function/nodes/node_fn_random_value.cc